# Workbook Subroutines cannot be called directly by name anymore from VB6

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I have a vb6 program that calls Macros from an Excel file.

Until recently it worked fine (for years), but now it throws an error.

We get a **runtime 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"** error.

As an example you can use this simple vb6 program:

```
Set App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wrkbook = App.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
App.visible = True
wrkbook.Test
```

The above code doesn't work anymore.
Instead, if we replace the last line with this:

```
wrkbook.Application.Run "ThisWorkbook.Test"
```

it works.
The Excel reference used for this, was "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library"

[image]

This has been tested against Excel 2010, 2013, Excel365 with the same results.
Also security settings are all set off in Excel.

Before changing my entire codebase and use Application.Run, I would know why this is happening.

Also using Application.Run has also some downsides, like calling both private & public subs and exceptions thrown are not propagated back to vb6.

Are there other considerations for using Application.Run?

Did Microsoft changed something lately (Scurity update), or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check if the workbook was opened properly. Before `wrkbook.Test` add `If Not wrkbook Is Nothing Then wrkbook.Test Else MsgBox "wb not opened properly"` • Also check if it works when moving the `Test` procedure into a public module instead of `ThisWorkbook` scope. • Also make sure the names are unique. For example that you don't have the name of the procedure `Test` anywhere else in your workbook. E.g if you have a module that is also called `Test` this can interfere.

Comment: @PEH thanks for the advices. Workbook opens properly. Even if I move the procedure in a public module it only works when i use application.Run. The Test procedure is the only one in the file, I created an new one just for testing. The code has always worked as it is, by calling workbook.Subname directly. It worked, until recently. And i don't know if I am doing something wrong or if Microsoft has made some changes regarding VBA.

Comment: Are you sure this method worked before from VB6? Because I cannot imagine any reason why Microsoft would remove that feature, and the only resources I can find online describe to use `Application.Run`. Not even one resource found that describes the method you use.

Comment: How is the wrkbook variable declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, thanks to @UuDdLrLrSs comment.
Problem was the use of early binding.
All Excel objects should use late binding.
More specific, the workbook should be declared as object:

```
Dim wrkbook As Object 'New Excel.Workbook
```

Otherwise it cannot recognize/find your Macro method.